# Export of Google Docs Automatic substitution items to text file?

Tags: google-docs

Google Docs has the ability to add items to the automatic substitution list in a nice way with the UI. I would like to take advantage of my list to be able to obtain a .csv or other text file with all the substitutions. (So I can add them as `iabbrev` mappings in Vim in particular). I could tease the items out of the raw HTML but was looking for an easier way.

Is this possible?